# What is the reason for using single-character generic type names in java?

Tags: java, generics

In java most (or all?) generic classes in the JDK have single-digit generic type names. For example `HashMap`'s definition looks like this:

```
public class HashMap<K,V> extends AbstractMap<K,V>
implements Map<K,V>, Cloneable, Serializable {
```

Why is this the convention instead of more descriptive type names like `HashMap<KEY,VALUE>` ?

Comment: There is obviously no objective answer to this question.

Comment: One reason could be to avoid verbosity

Comment: My first though when finding an identifier like KEY or VALUE in a Java file would be that they are constants... or classes poorly named. Besides, digit means number, not character

Comment: To add to @Pablo's comment, if I instead saw `Key` and `Value` I'd think they were actual concrete classes. `key` and `value` wouldn't fit in nicely with the rest of the Java language style conventions, so `K` and `V` seems to be the most reasonable choice to me

Comment: I saw it done that way in C++ when STL first came along.  I didn't need TYPE instead of T.  I don't think spelling them out adds value or understanding.

Comment: @javaguy When has that ever been an objective in Java? :)

Answer (score 5):

I think the main point here is simple convention. If you use single-letter for generic types and multiple-letter names for class names it comes obvious what you are dealing with. Also, if you used KEY or VALUE as you point, these names would look as constant names. Convention says:

```
UPPERCASE_AND_UNDERSCORE -> CONSTANTS

UpperCamelCase -> ClassNames

lowerCamelCase -> attributes

T,S,V -> genericTypes
```

Check out [the official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)

> **Type Parameter Naming Conventions**
>
> By convention, type parameter names are single, uppercase letters. This stands in sharp contrast to the variable naming conventions that you already know about, and with good reason: Without this convention, it would be difficult to tell the difference between a type variable and an ordinary class or interface name.
>
> The most commonly used type parameter names are:
>
> E - Element (used extensively by the Java Collections Framework)
>
> K - Key
>
> N - Number
>
> T - Type
>
> V - Value
>
> S,U,V etc. - 2nd, 3rd, 4th types
>
> You'll see these names used throughout the Java SE API and the rest of this lesson.

Comment: I actually regret that convention, and just found out sonar s00119 enforces it :-( Most of the time when I use generic, it has a precise meaning, even if it is generic about it's implementation. I feel like using single character names goes against [the general readability convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Readability).

Comment: I prefer the [google style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5.2.8-type-variable-names) that allows camel case names ending with a `T`, such as `ParameterT` when the meaning of this generic is "Parameter"